# How to setup my environment to use Code Blocks with C++

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

I'm new to C++ and trying to setup my environment

I downloaded and installed [code blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26)

Then I downloaded and installed [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) which was recommended under [Installing a supported compiler](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_a_supported_compiler#Compiler-neutral_setup_steps)

I'm trying to compile a simple program:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>

//std::ifstream t("C:\Users\Flights Trainer\Desktop\hosts-backup.txt");
std::ifstream t("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts-backup.txt");

t.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
str.reserve(t.tellg());
t.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

str.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

When I try to build, I get the error :

> ||=== Build: Debug in Hostapp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Hostapp\makechanges.c|1|fatal error: string: No such file or directory|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Reading the error, I see that the file "string" was not found, so I started poking around and found it under `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++` and added this folder to **Settings > Compiler > Search Directories**

[image]

That fixes the first error but now Im getting the below error in the `string` file:

> ||=== Build: Debug in Hostapp (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string|38|fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

There is a `bits` folder, but no `c++config.h` inside it

Here is the project setup:

[image]

**What do I need to do to setup my environment correctly and get this program to compile?**

Comment: your're sure your source filename is sth like `whatever.cpp`,  `whatever.cxx`, `whatever.c++` ? It appears it's `makechanges.c`which is a c, not a c++ source filename.

Comment: @decltype_auto Actually, it's `Hostapp.cbp`. Is that wrong? 
    http://prntscr.com/96ieam

Comment: You're talking about the CodeBlocks **project file**. I was talking about the C++-**source** filename.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that too @decltype_auto I added a picture of the folder structure in my project

Comment: simply rename that source file `makechanges.c` `makechanges.cpp`

Comment: Renaming the file caused another error as it still looked for the old one, but creating a new project worked, Thank you @decltype_auto, Throw up an answer and Ill accept it :)